# Testing related page in Wagtail

Tags: django, python-unittest, wagtail

I've got a `ContentPage` model in wagtail and a `RelatedPost` model that links other `ContentPage` models to `ContentPage` a bit like this:

```
class ContentPage(Page):
    summary = RichTextField(blank=True)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('summary'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('related_page', label="Related Content"),
    ]

    settings_panels = Page.settings_panels + [
        FieldPanel('published'),
    ]

class RelatedPost(Orderable):
    post = ParentalKey(
        'ContentPage',
        related_name='related_page'
    )
    page = models.ForeignKey(
        'ContentPage',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+"
    )
    panels = [
        FieldPanel('page')
    ]
```

When I run this test:

```
class ContentPageTests(WagtailPageTests):
    def test_can_create_article_page(self):
        self.assertCanCreateAt(ContentIndexPage, ContentPage)

        # content_index is just a parent page
        content_index = self.create_content_index_page()
        self.assertCanCreate(content_index, ContentPage, {
            'title': 'Test Article',
            'published': datetime.datetime.now()
        })
```

I get an error saying:

`django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']`

The admin works fine. I can save related pages etc and when I comment out the InlinePanel line it works fine.

Comment: The problem is not in views or models,but in the form or formset settings,So you need to post the forms.py file and your view,from which the form is getting rendered.

Comment: Also, you have not defined `create_content_index_page` in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data passed to `assertCanCreate` needs to match the format of a form submission being posted to the 'edit page' form in the Wagtail admin. For a child model in an InlinePanel, Wagtail handles this with a Django formset - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#formset-validation - and so you need to supply all the fields that the Django formset logic would expect, including the [management form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform). The simplest case that passes validation is a management form that simply reports that there are no child forms:

```
   self.assertCanCreate(content_index, ContentPage, {
        'title': 'Test Article',
        'published': datetime.datetime.now(),
        'related_page-TOTAL_FORMS': 0,
        'related_page-INITIAL_FORMS': 0,
        'related_page-MAX_NUM_FORMS': 999,
    })
```